# About store functions in a dictionary

Tags: c#

Today, I have seen the code like this

```
Dictionary<string, Func<string[], int>> functions = 
    new Dictionary<string, Func<string[], int>>
{
    { "Foo", CountParameters }
};

...

private static int CountParameters(string[] parameters)
{
    return parameters.Length;
}

// etc
```

I can invoke the function by

```
functions["Foo"](new string[1] { "1" });
```

of

```
CountParameters(new string[1] { "1" })
```

Anybody can help me explain why to use Dictionary and performance?

Comment: From [tagging help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging): _"The only time you should use tags in your title is when they are organic to the conversational tone of the title."_

Comment: [Related question on Software Engineering](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/264766/efficiency-of-c-dictionaries)

Comment: I'd suggest this code has little or nothing to do with performance.  To see any difference in performance between using a Dictionary or an ordinary collection to store and find your functions you would need to have tens of thousands or millions of functions to see performance differences.  It's likely you don't have anywhere near that many, so this code is more about ease of implementation and  design of code to solve a particular problem

Comment: functions["Foo"](new string[1] { "1" }); is going to be slower than simply calling CountParameters(new string[1] { "1" })

Comment: The purpose of a dictionary is to be dynamic. Functions can be freely added or removed and given any name at runtime. Perhaps the code you saw was written by a JavaScript programmer. lol

Comment: @Mick this is the answer I expected but can you show more detail about this?

Comment: You'd do something like this if you needed to map a string to a function you want to run.  The alternative would be a `switch` statement or a bunch of `if` statements.  Because presumeably the string is not known at run time.  If you saw this with actual literal strings being used instead of variables then it's either left over from when it was dynamic or it's an example of someone over engineering a solution.

Comment: @akurasu I think it's faily obvious, one is a static call, the other is doing a lookup on a dictionary then derefencing a pointer to a function and at this point would be up to the point you would be at if you just statically called the method.  There's two extra steps before the method is called, to test performance you would probably have to measure time across millions of executions to get any difference, but I would be astounded if functions["Foo"](new string[1] { "1" }); wasn't infinitesimally slower than CountParameters(new string[1] { "1" })

Comment: @akurasu without delving into the nuances of the CLR, you can only take a guess on what difference there is going to be in performance between two implementations like this.  But when you guess you can often be surprised.  With performance the only real way to gauge it is to instrument and test your code.  i.e. write code to record the time execute one method a million times... determine how long it took... then do the same with the other method.  There's no other way.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Why use a Dictionary? Because the keys are non-contigous. This is always the case with string keys, but can happen with integers just as well.

Why use string? Because a string index was needed or accidentally wanted/used. It could be that the datasource is operating in strings, or that the original coder did not understand that Enumerations were a thing.

Now performance is a tricky question. First of all, you should read the [speed rant](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/) to make sure you really needed the answer.

For equality checks, string is in a odd place. By default classes only check for reference equality. If both point to the same instance, they are the same. String goes the extra mile to include value equality. So if reference equality fails, it will do extra work. So it fails slowly, but matches quickly. And with keys you will get a lot of fails, before you ever (if at all!) get a match.
On the other hand, [string interning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_interning) is a thing in .NET. So strings with the exact same value tend to end up being the same instance.

If you are worried about the key type being to bad at comparision, you can use a HashTable. They basically do the same as a Dictionary, except they also store a integer hash value for each key. If the hashes do not match, you **know** they can not be the same. If they do match, you do the remaining comparision to avoid any hash colissions. So it tends to fail quickly, but matches slow-ish. The only downside is that you have to provide the Hash Function and need to write it right.

Edit: As Juharr pointed out, Dictionaries already work like HashTables, so that difference is purely academic. All classes inherit default hash behavior from Object (it uses something similar to reference equality for classes, reflection based value equality for structs), with String having a [proper implementation of GetHashCode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.gethashcode?view=netframework-4.8), but with a lot of caveats.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I want to know performance between call function through Dictionary and called by a function name

Comment: @akurasu Finding the function name in a dictionary is orders of magnitude slower then just coding out the function name. Wich is why you only ever do it that way if the function to call **can not** be hardcoded. It is like comparing the access to a constant with a lookup in a dictionary. Those are not even comparable things.

Comment: Dictionaries in C# are HashTables, they use a hash of the key to determine which bucket to put the values into.  Also `string` already has a hash algorithm so you'd only need to supply one for custom types or if you wanted a specific type of equality.

Comment: @juharr: Huh, apparently that hash table class was only there for COM Interop and similar oldschool stuff? I guess it does make sense to use Hashes, since GetHash is a function of Object. And especially for a Pre-writteen class, there is a decent chance it was coded out: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object.gethashcode?view=netframework-4.8#System_Object_GetHashCode

Comment: HashTable is the pre-generic version of Dictionary similar to ArrayList being the pre-generic version of List.  I assume they decided to go with different names to differentiate them.